# An impure square

Tags: word, wordplay

Something's a bit *off* in the square below - some might say it's impure.

```
D O R A N
R E N Y K
A G E T C
M L L I A
O W H L B
```

What's special about the square, and what's wrong? (There are actually two things wrong, though they complement each other.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing that's special is that it contains

> a number of colour words that can be read off Boggle-style:
>
>  * red
>  * yellow
>  * magenta
>  * white
>  * black
>  * orange
>  * cyan

That includes

> The two main tones: white and black;
>  Two of the three primary-school primary colours: red and yellow (the third being blue);
>  The three "true" secondary colours, also used in printing: cyan, magenta, yellow

So there's one missing element and one extra element,

> blue and orange, which are [used in visual arts for their contrast](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OrangeBlueContrast).

Comment: You're very much onto something, and are very close with your newest discovery, but this is unfortunately not complete. You have the two things named in the second half of your answer, but what are they, and in what way do they complement each other? (The "official" answer to this puzzle could be of the form "X and Y")

Comment: You've got it now, and I'll give it to you, but the last bit had a keyword I was looking for. ;)

Comment: @WilliamZ, "complementary", as hinted at in the last sentence of the question? I would tend to disagree, and the mention of "primary school" might give a hint as to why.

Comment: Indeed, on both counts.

Comment: I was going for additive/subtractive instead of "primary"/"secondary" anyhow; the latter pairing is more disputable.